# Ayuda con send_file Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Temgo el siguiente problema. Trato de mostrar una lista de archivos que estan alojados en el servidor . Los archivos están alojados en /home/drakmond/Practicas/Yipi/logsLoader y con extension .txt.

El codigo del controlador es el siguiente:

```
class Admin::LogsController < AdminController

    Directorio = "/home/drakmond/Practicas/Yipi/logsLoader"

    def listar_archivos
        @archivos = Dir.entries(Directorio)
        send_file "#{Rails.root}/logsLoader/#{params[:file_name]}"
    end

end
```

Y el codigo de mi vista es:

```
<section class="content-header">
  <h1><%= t('top_menu.logs')%></h1>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="<%= admin_dashboard_path %>"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <%= t('breadcrumb.home')%></a></li>
    <li><a href="<%= admin_yipi_devices_path %>"><%= t('device.index.head')%></a></li>
    <li class="active"><%= t('top_menu.logs')%></li>
  </ol>
</section>
<section class='content'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box box-warning">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <ul>
                        <% @archivos.each do |a| %>
                        <% if a == "." or a == ".." then next end; %>
                        <li>
                            <strong> <%= a %> </strong> |
                            <%= link_to "Descargar", admin_logs_listar_archivos_path, :action => :listar_archivos, :file_name => a %>| 
                        </li>
                        <% end %>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Pero con eso el sistema me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Cannot read file /home/drakmond/Practicas/Yipi/logsLoader/
```

Alguien sabe que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta tratando de leer la carpeta porque `params[:file_name]` va vacío. La forma correcta de pasar parámetros es: `<%= link_to "Descargar", admin_logs_listar_archivos_path(:file_name => a), :action => :listar_archivos %>`

Comment: Oh es cierto, estaba enviando mal los parámetros. Muchas gracias por hacerme notar mi error.